# Lightweight fork replacement for threads

Tags: perl

I would like to use `fasync` below similar to `threads async`. Am I forgetting something, are there some corner cases which are not covered here?

```
sub fasync(&) {
  my ($worker) = @_;

  my $pid = fork() // die "can't fork!";

  if (!$pid) {
    $worker->();
    exit(0);
  }

  return sub {
    my ($flags) = @_;
    return waitpid($pid, $flags // 0);
  }
}

my @join = map {
  my $job = $_;
  fasync {

    print "$job\n";
  };
} 1 .. 10;

$_->() for @join;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That looks like it should work just fine, although there should be an error check on `fork` (it returns `undef` on failure), and it needs elaboration if you want any means of communicating between the children and the parent, or between different children.